# ExpiredToken error when using python moto lib to mock s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-unittest, moto

I am new to Python. Anyone knows how moto mock test work? I am going to test the code which will fetch data from S3 and convert data and upload to S3. I used moto lib to mock s3, however it shows "An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the ListObjects operation" when calling S3 from my code.

Do I need to mock aws credential? How should I mock it? (I check the moto lib and there is no such thing mock_arn/mock_credential )

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code: inside parse_requests method, it will fetch data from S3 and convert data, then upload to S3.

```
Class Test_processing_data(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_s3 = mock_s3()
        self.mock_s3.start()
        self.mock_logs = mock_logs()
        self.mock_logs.start()
        self.bucket_region = "us-east-1"
        self.bucket_name = "test-bucket"
        self.s3_client = boto3.client("s3", region_name=self.bucket_region)
        self.s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=self.bucket_name)

    @mock_s3
    def test_parse_requests(self):
        bucket_name = "test-bucket"
        prefix = "test/model/main/"
        execution_date = "2022/09/13/12"

        parse_requests(execution_date, bucket_name, prefix)
```

Here is the error message:

```
self = <botocore.client.S3 object at 0x10abf18e0>
operation_name = 'ListObjects'
api_params = {'Bucket': 'campaign-performance-forecasting-offline', 'EncodingType': 'url', 'Prefix': 'test/model/main/2022/09/13/12'}

...

       if http.status_code >= 300:
            error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
            error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
>           raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
E           botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the ListObjects operation: The provided token has expired.

../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py:914: ClientError
```

Comment: It looks like the test still reaches out to AWS. That may be due to the import order, as Moto is a bit finicky about that. See http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/getting_started.html#what-about-those-pesky-imports

Comment: @BertBlommers I have followed link you provided and implemented the code, it still didn't work. Any other suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share the full, reproducible, test? Simplified if necessary, as long as it can be reproduced - that makes it easier to figure out what may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Mocks should be established BEFORE the clients are set up. You seem to have `s3_client` established outside mock and it might be causing this issue.

Try setting up mock before the function or class and give it a try. I hope this helps.